# Optimum thread count NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

We're trying to figure out the optimum number of threads to use for our NServiceBus service. We're running it on a machine with 2 quad cores. We've been having problems with the queue backing up. We started with 100 threads then bumped it to 200 and things got worse. We backed it down to 75, then 50 and it seemed even better. Is there some optimal number based on how many CPU's we have or some rule of thumb that we should use to determine the number of threads to run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every thread you have running has an overhead attached to it. If you have 2 quad cores then you will be able to have exactly 8 threads running at any one time. Each thread will be consuming a core.

If you have more than 8 threads then there is a chance you will start to do LESS useful work, not more. This is because every time windows decides to give one of the threads not currently consuming a core a turn at doing something it needs to store the state of one of the running threads and then restore the old state of the thread that is about to run - then let the thread go at it. If you have a huge number of threads you're going to spend a large amount of time just switching between the threads and doing nothing useful.

If you have a bunch of threads that are blocked waiting for IO (for instance a message to finish writing to disk so it can be got at) then you might be able to run more threads than you have cores and still get something useful done as a number of those threads will be sitting waiting for something else to complete. It's a complex subject and there is no real answer to 'how many threads should I use'. A good rule of thumb is have a thread for every core and then try and play with it a bit if you want to achieve more throughput. Testing it under real conditions is the only real way to find the sweet spot. You might find that you only need one thread to process the messages and half the time that thread is blocked waiting for a message to come in....

Obviously, even what I've described is oversimplified. Windows needs access to the cores to do OSy things so even if you have 8 cores all of your 8 threads wont always be running because the windows threads are having a turn... then you have IO threads etc....

Comment: In addition to that, whatever work your NServiceBus code is doing is going to come into play. If a message handler is dependent upon a database, which introduces locking and other contention, then increasing the number of threads would increase deadlocks, making more messages fail and have to be retried. The answer is always going to depend on the individual application.